# $A$ with equation of more than one matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I need to write a matrix, that has a structure as in the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use  the `align` environment and `bmatrix`, both from `amsmath`.

Comment: Unrelated: The attached picture is wrong `:-)` The off-diagonal terms of the matrix in the second line need a sign too...

Comment: I’d rather use the `split` environment inside an `align` (or `align*`): indeed, the two lines are part of a single equation, which should get a *single* equation number, not two (one would hardly want to refer to each line separately!).  i’d align at the “=” sign, too (as opposed to aligning the second “=” with “t”).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that complements the comments by @Bernard and @campa. Observe that the first row may be simplified by multiplying `t` into `I_n`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
tI_n-A 
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
t & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & t & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots& \vdots& \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & t 
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
t-a_{11}& -a_{12} & \dots & -a_{1n} \\
-a_{21} & t-a_{22}& \dots & -a_{2n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots& \vdots  \\
-a_{n1} & -a_{n2} & \dots & t-a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```